# Adding Tab to Page

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

I am trying to add the tab to a page I am admin of. 
I use the url to do that - 
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=&next=.

Facebook shows a list of all the pages I am admin of. And that drop down has no specific sorting order.

Now my problem is -  I have multiple pages with same page name. They ofcourse have different urls. I tried changing the name of pages, but due to high number of likes I can't change the names.

The only option I am left with is hit & Trial. And I have to do it for more than 30 apps.

So you understand my pain point.

Please advice any alternative.

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing down the page ids and making some sort of system for yourself to remember (perhaps only the last few digits) which page is which.

In any case, there is a way for you to add a tab application directly to a page without ever seeing that "Add Page Tab" dialog. You can do it all through the API. This means you'll need your pages access token so head on over to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), make sure you click the "get access token" button and mark the `manage_pages` permission.

1. You need to query `/me/accounts` to get a list of all the pages you administer.
   You'll see a list with the page id, name, category... I hope you will be able to identify your page more easily here. Once you have, you'll need to get the **`access_token`** for that page. Keep a record of it - we'll need it in a few minutes. You'll also need the **page id**.
2. Modify the following URL to include the parameters we got previously -

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=TAB_APP_ID&method=post&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Navigate to that URL and if all goes well, you'll get a simple `true` message indicating that the action was successful.